# AI combine objects - both compound path and pathfinders failed?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have a AI file like the following picture (1) and I want combine the objects into one single object.

[image: AI Object]

Then I make a compound path, it became NO FILL, NO STROKE, like following picture (2)
[image: Compound path failed]

Then I try to use UNITE in Pathfindes, it became a black objects, like following picture (3)
[image]

Can help me how to make it into one single object ?

Actually, I want make it in one single object and export to SVG, any other methods to do this ?

Thanks

Comment: Expand appearances then do a pathfinder merge. Then delete the white.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to fill the compound path afterward to check appearance?...there are occasions when the creation of a new compound path results in an object with blank fill and blank stroke attributes.
Generally speaking, though, you should only make compound paths from components that are closed paths and ones in which all fills (and what may appear as strokes)
are outlined by closed paths.  Attempting to make compound paths from open paths will not work as Illustrator will be forced to join open paths (usually with straight lines...thereby altering the appearance)
Judging by how complex your illustration is...compound paths may fail to print or output correclty. If you are exporting as SVG just keep the objects as a group, there is no need to use compound paths...compound paths are designed to solve very specific graphic requirements - technically they work on certain rules to achieve their appearance (for example even/odd rule) so the rule of thumb is keep it simple and reduce path complexity. complex paths are best achieved by grouping simpler compound paths...witness what occurs when you convert a body of text into paths (outlines) by using the software instruction "create outlines"